# Angular 2 delayed update of model in component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-components

I am new to Angular 2 and I've recently been trying the two-way binding. I have the following code:

**template.html**

```
<select [(ngModel)]="val" (change)="onChanged()">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>1</option>
</select>
```

**component.ts**

```
..//other code definitions here
export class MyComponent{
  val: number = 1; //edited this

  onChanged(){
    console.log(this.val);
  }
}
```

The problem is when the selected value on the dropdown changes, the value outputted on the console is still the previous value. It only updates after I select again another value, but the printed value was still the previously selected value. So it's like delayed by one selection.

Hope anyone can help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The `val` value will only be updated on the next Angular2 change detection cycle. To use the latest value in `onChanged` method, consume `$event` value like this:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="val" (change)="onChanged($event)">
```

In `MyComponent`:

```
onChanged(newVal){
  console.log(newVal);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't it defeat the purpose of 2 way binding? I'll have to clutter my functions with parameters where I already have a model bound to the view.

Comment: IMO it does not. 2-way data binding still being reserved (as in the value in parent component is updated eventually). What you need here is another concern: How to perform some actions on that particular event. Cluttering 2 different concerns into 1 is the easiest way to get headaches.

Answer (score 2):

When you use two-way binding - `[(ngModel)]`, always use `(ngModelChange)` instead of `(change)`:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="val" (ngModelChange)="onChanged()">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>1</option>
</select>
```

Here's [working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hkovuyfIzw32WEGQix8v?p=preview).

Comment: Yes but the thing is the onChanged() function is being called twice when I use the ngModelChange.

Comment: I've edited my post, i've missed something on the val declaration.

Comment: @Jed It still gets called once on every change, check out the Plunker I provided again.

Comment: I'm not really sure what's going on with my code, but the code inside my onChange is actually fetching from server so I just created a boolean variable to check if the promise hasn't returned yet this way it doesn't execute twice. Im not sure if it's a clean workaround but it's working. Thank you for your help.